# python: my py2exe windows app makes .dat AND (unwanted) .bat file AND (unwanted) .dir file

Tags: python, py2exe

I am using the shelve module and create .dat files from my python app when they're needed by the user.

However when I ported the application to .exe using the py2exe module I'm getting three files, a `.dat`, `.bat`  and `.dir`. How can I get rid of them and consolidate into one .dat file like I had on the IDLE API.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal example that does this, which version of python are you using with py2exe? Are you running it on a networked drive or a local drive? What filesystem?

Comment: To correct the above ... sorry I have been getting .dat .bak and .dir files made when my .exe application shelves. I made my .exe with py2exe using 32 bit and 64 bit machines and the corresponding download. Both produced the same 3 files. My setup file for py2exe had the 'includes' list with 'dumb.dbm'

Comment: the basic code for shelving is

Comment: @Nilambar the basic code for the shelving is quite simple : `shelve.open(myfile)` which happens without `myfile` needing a file extension such as .dat etc. The version I am using on both machines is python 2.7.10 the py2exe is the most recent at time of writing july 2015 sorry can't find the exact version name

Comment: from looking at the help files on dumbdbm, this module opens both a .dat and a .dir file to make the database function.

Comment: I assume the .bak is for the traceback facility. The question is - how do I consolidate these 3 into 1 file?